# Using "memory_order::relaxed" or "memory_order::acq_rel" to generate unique IDs?

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic, memory-model

I have read in several places that relaxed ordering was ok to generate unique IDs. I have a doubt about that, because if two threads call at the same time:

`uniqueId.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed);`

Then the value incremented by thread-A might not be visible yet to thread-B. This means, both threads could get the same unique ID.

For this reason, I would rather use `std::memory_order::acq_rel`

What do you think?

Impossible to test, in practice.

Comment: Changes to the atomic itself should still be observed in some total order, even with relaxed semantics. The difference between relaxed and acquire/release lies in whether and which changes to *other* variables become visible to the thread that reads the atomic written to by another thread.

Comment: Your concern is not about how this access is ordered, only that it is atomic.  `std::atomic::fetch_add` is always atomic.

Comment: One great advantage of using `seq_cst` would be that you could write `uniqueId++`.

Comment: @DrewDormann "atomic" itself is not a guarantee. Atomic means the instruction is uninterruptible by another thread, hence cannot be partially executed. It does not guarantee something about the actual memory being "visible".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am not sure about what you say (if I understand you right). If this was true, smart pointers could only use relaxed ordering for their reference counter. But the stl implementations I have seen use relaxed for incrementing the counter and acq_rel to decrement it (to be safe and not deleting a dangling pointer).

Comment: @Philippe Shared pointers need acq/rel (to some degree) in order to synchronize the state of the _managed object_ before the last shared pointer calls the destructor on it. It is not necessary to keep the reference count consistent.

Comment: @Philippe The fences used on a shared pointer decrement is not to prevent a double delete (again, `std::atomic` always guarantees this to be safe).  It's to ensure that the one thread performing the delete is deleting the correct object state.

Comment: @DrewDormann Are you saying that the fences are only need when managing a mutable data structure? Shared data structures are very often immutable once they are shared. (They aren't declared `const`, but there is often no legit way to change the shared object.)

Comment: @Philippe "_But the stl implementations_" Nitpick: the STL doesn't have smart pointers. STL means Standard Template Library, it has "containers", "iterators", "algorithm" that uses iterators, adaptors for use of these... A `shared_ptr` is neither.

Answer (score 7):

`std::memory_order_*` is about how stores and loads to memory locations *other* than the atomic object itself synchronize.

A single atomic object's value is always consistent among all threads. It has exactly one modification order that all threads agree on and that is consistent with sequencing of loads/stores in each thread, regardless of `std::memory_order_*`.

(However this is true only for each atomic object viewed individually. The same does not apply between multiple atomic objects.)

Whether `std::memory_order::relaxed` is sufficient in your case depends on whether the resulting ID values are going to be used through other shared objects (whether atomic or not) between the threads, but the expression

```
uniqueId.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed)
```

, even when used in multiple threads will generate each ID only once (assuming `uniqueId` refers to the same `std::atomic` object, no other stores are applied to it and no overflow/wrap-around happens). It is important though that `fetch_add` itself is an atomic read-modify-write. A load followed by a store would not be an atomic operation and wouldn't guarantee that no store from another thread intervenes between the load and store.

Comment: BTW, the guarantee that RMW operations always load "the latest value" is there for this reason (creating a single modification order where every increment is seen once), not anything about seeing stores sooner in time (inter-thread latency or avoiding "stale" values.)